# How to add pagination for a page of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I use the following code to display product in single page:

[product_category category="CUSTOMIZE" per_page="9" columns="3" orderby="date" order="desc"]

However, when the product exceed 9, it's not direct to next page. How to add pagination to this code?

Thanks!

Comment: The likelihood is there is some code related to the plugin your are using for this. So tell us a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm using woocommerce shopping cart, and the theme is Maya theme. It's wordpress

Comment: hopefully my answer is usefull, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like currently woocommerce plugin does not actually support pagination on a products page.

See here http://ideas.woothemes.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/4146798-add-pagination-support-for-list-of-products-render

There seems to be two common work arounds.

A:  In your wordpress settings. Change the max amount of posts visible on a page and therefore all products are shown, hence no more need for pagination. Alternatively of course you could also set your per_page attribute to some ridiculous number.

B: Download the plugin wp-navi. Activate it and configure it. Then add the following code to your functions.php in your theme folder.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_pagination', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);
function woocommerce_pagination() {
wp_pagenavi();      
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_pagination', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);
```

Unfortunately there seems to be no definitive answer for this at the moement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a tragedy for me to know that that line of code can't display product. The current woocommerce product page has no sidebar, I need to add sidebar for that, and customize it...